# How do I get separated parts to function together in an animation?

Tags: animation, .fbx

I have an FBX file that I am importing into Blender.  This character has an animation included, but the problem is, while the body is animating correctly, the eyes came through as a separate object (mesh?), and they aren't being animated.  Here's a screen capture of what this looks like in object mode:

[image]

The eyes are in their default, non-animated position.  I know this is true because when I select the head and go into edit mode, this is what I see:

[image]

For some reason, the eyes aren't being animated. I could delete the animation from the head and body, and that would line everything up properly, but I really want to use the animation.  How can I make the animation apply to the eyes as well as the head?

Comment: Are the eyes parented to the bone that controls the head?

Comment: Hmm.  I just went into Pose mode, and it looks like the eyes don't have bones.

Comment: Them having no bones will only cause the issue that you wont be able to animate them using the same rig (Unless you make changes to it). But what I am asking is whether the eyes, the object itself, the mesh, is it parented to the bone that controls the head. (This will PROBABLY be the big bone in the middle of your head.) If they are, in no way, connected to the rig/armature, they wont move when you make changes to the armature/rig in the pose mode.

Comment: I didn't realize I could parent an object to a bone.  There is a bone clearly labeled "head".

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.  In object mode, the eyes are in the default position, and therefore are offset from their correct position, which would be inside the head.  If I go into edit mode with the rig selected, the body reverts to the rest position, which means it aligns correctly with the eyes, but then I can't select the eyes or do anything with them.

Comment: Sorry, messed up my words wayyyyy too much. Basically parent the eyes to the armature. And weight paint if needed. (Use automatic weights)

Comment: If all vertices of an object are under the influence of a single bone, and are not influenced by any other bone, then, atleast in the practical sense of it, I would call that obj parented to the bone. But in the techical terms, the object is parented to the armature, and never to the bone. I apologize for the confusion that I created.